# How do I run microbenchmarks in CUDA without the optimizer messing with me?

Tags: cuda, microbenchmark

I've been trying to benchmark the modulus operation in CUDA against some custom modulus operations, currently I use the following function.

```
__inline__ __device__ uint64_t modop(uint64_t& a, uint32_t& q) {
    uint64_t c;
    for (int j = 0; j < REPEAT; j++) {
        c = a % q;
    }
    return c;
}
```

My problem is that I believe the compiler is being clever and optimizing the loop away as it's unreasonably fast. I've trying clobbering my variables with `asm volatile("" : "=l"(c)::"memory");` but for `a` it does nothing and for `c` it breaks everything.

What can I do to benchmark simple operations like this on CUDA?

Comment: The compiler eliminates all "dead" code that is not contributing to globally visible state (i.e. is needed to deliver data to global memory) and also all redundant operations (your loop computes the same value over and over again). It is also applying constant propagation, strength reduction, induction variables. Build a dependency chain (e.g. a sum or XOR of modulo results), store its result to global memory at the end, make sure none of the initial inputs are discoverable at compile time (so, generally kernel arguments) and vary the arguments to operation under test with each iteration.

Comment: For benchmarking kernels there is the official [nvbench](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvbench). For a microbenchmark like yours I have recently seen [cuda_benchmark](https://github.com/senior-zero/cuda_benchmark) by a NVIDIA employee. Haven't tried it out myself yet, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

There is in-kernel measurement with clock_t returning function clock(). You can use its return value to stop optimizations too (like repeating until clock increments at least 1000 cycles and then measuring number of repeats to be divided by total cycles). Compiler can not predict time.

```
clock_t a =clock();
clock_t q =clock();
int repeats=0;
while(q-a<1000)
{
    c=a%q;
    repeats++;
    q=clock();
}


perf = repeats / (float)(q - a - (latencyClock + latencyIncrement)*repeats);
```

Then in performance calculations, subtract clock()(and ++) latency times repeats from total latency.

This enforces each thread to run a different value of modulo as opposed to a single-kernel code for all threads. So the kernel can not be optimized globally.

Comment: CUDA? And calling `clock` in a tight loop? Even if this would work (which I doubt), it would be profiling the speed of `clock()` not `%`

Comment: Isnt clock latency constant?

Comment: Where else you can exclude kernel launch latency, host buffer copy latency, sync latency, video-ram access latency, L1 cache latency and loop increment latency? In question, he is getting all these latencies.